# Starting lxterminal in default directory

Tags: lxterminal

Is there a way to create a file to be stored on the desktop - which when clicked will startup `lxterminal` in a specific directory?

I have four programs I am running in `lxterminal` and want to be able to click on four files on the desktop which will startup an instance of `lxterminal` in a specific directory without having to do

```
cd /home 
cd xxx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `--working-directory` option. So

```
lxterminal --working-directory=/path/to/dir
```

will open the terminal with the current directory set to`/path/to/dir`.

Regarding having clickable files the open `lxterminal` in *different* working directories, create four *different* (executable) scripts, which open `lxterminal` in the required directories and save them to your desktop. So

```
/bin/sh
lxterminal terminal --working-directory=/path/to/dir1
```

and

```
/bin/sh
lxterminal terminal --working-directory=/path/to/dir2
```

and so on.

See the the [`lxterminal` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/lxterminal.1.html).

To make the script executable, there is no need for a *specific* file extension, although `.sh` is sometimes used<sup>1</sup>. Use the command [`chmod`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?chmod). Run `chmod 755 <scriptname>`, or `chmod +x <scriptname>` on the scripts. So, if the path to your script is `/home/pi/Desktop/myscript` run

```
chmod +x /home/pi/Desktop/myscript
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that the extension `.sh` will not make the file excutable, it is merely a sometimes used convention, to denote that the file contains a (sh) script.

Comment: what file name extension would I save the file as for it to be recognized as an executable?

Comment: `--working-directory` seems to only work with absolute path. So, use `--working-directory=/home/your_username/path/to/dir` but not `--working-directory=~/path/to/dir`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto the previous answer...

I found that the extra "terminal" in the sh file was causing failure.  In my case (with raspbian Stretch from June of 2019) I needed a file like this:

```
/bin/sh
lxterminal --working-directory=/path/to/dir
```

Also, I will reiterate the other comment that this requires absolute path.  You have to include the /home and user to open the terminal in a folder for a given user.  For example:

```
/home/pi/Documents/HiddenTreasure/MyPreciousFiles
```

Lastly, you can avoid the prompt that asks you if you want to **execute** or **execute in terminal** by triggering this script from a desktop shortcut.  You make an empty file on the desktop and then populate with some stuff.  There are many tutorials online but here is an example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=OpenMyFileWithoutHassle
Exec=/home/pi/Desktop/OpenMyPreciousFilesInTerminal.sh
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/openbox.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

This example will open the script `OpenMyPreciousFilesInTerminal.sh` that is on the desktop.  But, you can put your sh script anywhere you'd like which will keep your desktop cleaner...

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, when you click on application icons in the menu or the launch bar, they start in the same directory that `lxpanel` was started from. So, if you want to start all your apps in `/home` instead of `~`, you can modify `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` to start `lxpanel` from `/home`.